# Floyd Compactification

Tags: geometric-group-theory, metric-geometry

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group, $f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ is a function satisfying $1<\frac{f(n)}{f(n+1)}<\lambda$ and $\sum f(n)<\infty$, which we called a floyd scaling function. Then if we consider a finite generating set $S$ for $G$, then we can consider the floyd compactification of $G$, denoted by $\bar{G_f}$. I know that the fact if $G$ is a hyperbolic group and $f(n)=\frac{1}{n^2+1}$, then its floyd boundary is homeomorphic to its Gromov boundary. But I want to prove the fact rigorusly that the floyd boundary of a genus $g\geq 2$ is non-trivial i.e. contains infinitely many points. But don't know how to proceed.

Further it will be helpful if anyone suggest some good literature on floyd compactification. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you used the algebraic-geometry tag? That phrase does not refer to the general blending of algebra and geometry but specifically to the geometry of polynomial equations. The geometric-group-theory tag is, I think, sufficient here.

Comment: It's unclear to me what tools you are willing to use and what do you know about the subject. For instance, you are saying that you already know that for a hyperbolic group the Floyd boundary is homeomorphic to the Gromov boundary. Do you know how to identify the Gromov boundary of a genus $g\ge 2$ surface? Do you know how to prove that it is infinite? As for your reference request: What references on the subject do you know and why are they insufficient?